# join vm to domain in vpc on aws

Tags: active-directory, amazon-web-services, amazon-vpc

I have created a Virtual Private Cloud(VPC) on AWS. I have created two Windows Server R2 machines. One of them I have added Active Directory role and promoted it to a Domain Controller. I want to add the second machine to the domain. The following are the IP configurations:

Domain Controller

```
DHCP Enabled: Yes
IPv4 Address: 10.0.0.163
IPv4 Subnet Mask: 255.255.255.0
IPv4 Default Gateway: 10.0.0.1
IPv4 DHCP Server: 10.0.0.1
IPv4 DNS Server: 10.0.0.163
```

Second Machine:

```
DHCP Enabled: Yes
IPv4 Address: 10.0.0.143
IPv4 Subnet Mask: 255.255.255.0
IPv4 Default Gateway: 10.0.0.1
IPv4 DHCP Server: 10.0.0.1
IPv4 DNS Server: 10.0.0.163
```

When I try to join, I get an error stating that the domain does not exist. I tried pinging one server machine from the other and even that timed out. Is there anything else I need to do(specific to AWS) so that I can join the domain?

Answer (score 0):

does the domain actually exist publicly, or is it a private domain?
If (as I suspect) your domain is not public, then you should add the DNS role to your domain controller, and configure the second machine to use your domain controller as DNS server.
You can configure your VPC so that every instance spawned within this VPC will use this server as DNS, using [dhcp options sets](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/fr_fr/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/VPC_DHCP_Options.html) (you can also provide a list of DNS if you need more than this one)

Comment: Both the machines have a public IP address associated to them. I have set the Primary DNS Server of the second server to be the Private IP address of the DC.

Comment: I am not able to ping one VM from the other. Is that relevant?

Comment: did you allow ping in the security group assigned to the DC?

Comment: also in security groups, did you open port 53 for DNS? I recommend to open all traffic between your instances during the debug, and to harden later on when you will have identified the root cause

Comment: Port 53 is open. Have opened all ports actually and have also enabled ICMP in the security group

Comment: In the primary DNS Server, I have assigned the Private IP address of the domain controller. Is that what I have to provide or is it something else?

Comment: no that is correct. Can you nslookup your domain name in verbose mode? sth like https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc940085.aspx

Comment: btw, is ping ok now?

Comment: nope. ping still does not work. i get the address as 10.0.0.163 which is the local IP address of the DC. I ran it in the DC itself

Comment: did you shut the windows firewall down?

Comment: i haven't shut it down but there are firewall rules in place

Comment: firing questions as they come: can you try with firewall disabled anyway? does nslookup from the second machine work? instead of ping, can you try from the second machine to the DC a "Test-NetConnection 10.0.0.163 -port 53"? also one question I have in mind, just in case: I assume you did not change the route table of your VPC?

Comment: i haven't changed the route table. using the default one. nslookup does not work from the second machine. i guess there is some issue with being in the same subnet. something to do with DNS Server IP's

Comment: what error do you get (verbose mode) with the nslookup? there is no problem being on the same subnet, this is not the root cause. can you try with windows firewall disabled? the only blocking causes can be routing (this is out of scope here, as it is same subnet), security groups or the machine firewall. I see no other possibility

Comment: DNS request timed out.
    timeout was 2 seconds.
Default Server:  UnKnown
Address:  10.0.0.163

mydomain.com
Server:  UnKnown
Address:  10.0.0.163

Comment: do you have a reverse lookup zone configured for your domain? pretty sure this comes from a DNS missconfiguration... from an AWS point of view everything seems correct

Comment: http://www.rickygao.com/how-to-solve-nslookup-shown-unknown-for-the-default-dns-server/